# GitHub Actions to enforce proper branch names & PR merging

Tags: git, github, github-actions

In our project we want:

- all git branches made against our `dev` branch to match this regex

  ```
  ^(bug|feature|code-cleanup)\/JIRA-\d+-.+$
  ```

  *examples: `bug/JIRA-123-fix-login-issue` or `code-cleanup/JIRA-4567-enable-code-linting`*
- all branches made against our `qa` branch to match this regex

  ```
  ^kickback\/JIRA-\d+-.+$
  ```

  *example: `kickback/JIRA-123-fix-login-issue-again`*
- enforce that if a branch name begins with `kickback/` then a PR can only be made against the `qa` branch.

I have found some GitHub Actions like [`nicklegan/github-repo-branch-naming-policy-action`](https://github.com/nicklegan/github-repo-branch-naming-policy-action) and [`deepakputhraya/action-branch-name`](https://github.com/deepakputhraya/action-branch-name) which allows a global branch name regex pattern enforcement, but it doesn't seem like there is a way to specify different rule for different branch bases. If there was this would take care of the first two bullet point above, but not the 3rd one.

How can I enforce these checks for validating branch names are correct and PRs are made against the correct base branch?

Comment: [Metadata restrictions](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/available-rules-for-rulesets#metadata-restrictions) come to mind, but they're only available on GitHub Enterprise.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you question, but would that be ok:
1. Check if branch maches dev regex. If so check if pull_request target is `dev`. If so - workflow passed, If not...
2. check if branch matches qa regex. Ifo so check if its target is `qa` branch. If so - passed. If not...
3. Fail workflow.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes I saw that, but we do not have Enterprise which is why I am looking for a manual workaround with Actions - and it seems like it would be possible to do!

Comment: @ravenwing Yes I agree. How would I go about doing that in a YAML file? Or perhaps there is a better way to do this is that isn't in a YAML/github actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created repo here which demonstrates one of many ways to do it. [HERE](https://github.com/raven-wing/check_pull_request_branch)

1. Copy code to your workflow and customize it for your needs
2. Go to your repo `Settings -> rules -> ruleset`
3. Create new `rulset -> new branch rulesets`
4. Set target branchas to all.
5. Set `Require status checks to pass -> name it whatever -> chose github actions`
6. Save and enjoy.

---

But essentially it's this code:

```yaml
name: Check Pull Request
on: pull_request

jobs:
  check_pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check if PR target branch is ok
        run: |
          branch_name=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF}
          echo "pr branch name: $branch_name"
          
          target_branch=${GITHUB_BASE_REF}
          echo "target branch: $target_branch"
          dev_regex="^(bug|feature|code-cleanup)/JIRA-[0-9]+.*$"
          qa_regex="^kickback/JIRA-[0-9]+.*$"
          
          if [[ "$branch_name" =~ $dev_regex ]]; then
            echo "Branch name matches the first regex pattern."
            if [[ "$target_branch" != "dev" ]]; then
              echo "but doesn't match target branch"
              exit 1
            fi
          elif [[ "$branch_name" =~ $qa_regex ]]; then
            echo "Branch name matches the second regex pattern."
            if [[ "$target_branch" != "qa" ]]; then
              echo "but doesn't match target branch"
              exit 1
            fi
          else
            echo "Branch name does not match any regex. Exiting..."
            exit 1
          fi
        shell: bash
```

---

It did took me a while, so I could make some mistakes - if so, please share I'll fix them :)

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much!  I am not very familiar with bash/shell scripting so just seeing this saved me a ton of time figuring out the logic.  I've basically taken this and modified it for my needs since I left out a few specific details in my question. _(One minor thing in your script is the check for the QA pattern then checks the `dev` branch, but it should check the `qa` branch instead.)_  Here's what I'm using now: https://gist.github.com/FiniteLooper/dcdbc18812964efb1db5c342c0fbaea1

Comment: Ok, so it seems to run just fine, but when I did a test with a branch named `kickback/DTD-123-testing-pr-integration` against the `dev` branch it seems to be hitting my final `else` block instead matching the `qa_regex` and giving me the message about not being based on the `qa` branch. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Figured it out.  I can't use `\d` in bash regex patterns,m have to use `[0-9]` instead

Comment: Thanks for sharing your fixes. Updated accordingly!